# Finding items in child table referencing records in master table not referenced by other children

Tags: sql, oracle11g, null

I've a database with two table `MasterTable` and `ChildrenTable`, there is a one-to-many relationship between them. *(of course this is only part of the database)*

I need to find records in `ChildrenTable` which are the only records referencing item in master table. (e.g. I need to find Child1 if that's the only child linked to Master1, but not to find Child2 if also Child3 is linked to Master2).

I know I could've done it with a subquery too, but I thought this other approach would be easier:

```
SELECT
  MasterTable.Name,
  ChildrenTable.Name
FROM 
  MasterTable INNER JOIN ChildrenTable
  ON MasterTable.ID = ChildrenTable.MasterID
  LEFT JOIN ChildrenTable ChildrenTable1
  ON MasterTable.ID = ChildrenTable1.MasterID
WHERE
  ChildrenTable.Name = 'SomeName' 
  AND ChildrenTable.ID <> NVL(ChildrenTable1.ID,0)
  AND ChildrenTable1.ID Is Null;
```

But this query doesn't give me any results. When I exclude last condition I get results, but only those where `ChildrenTable1.ID` is not null (I've checked the data and there are records should be found.)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's SQL Server syntax. Not sure if it translates directly to Oracle's dialect:

```
SELECT MAX(ID), MasterID
FROM ChildrenTable
WHERE MasterID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MasterID
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

If children can exist in different tables, an option might be to UNION them:

```
SELECT MAX(u.ID), u.MasterID
FROM 
(
 SELECT c1.ID, c1.MasterID
 FROM ChildrenTable c1
 WHERE c1.MasterID IS NOT NULL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT c2.ID, c2.MasterID
 FROM SomeOtherChildTable c2
 WHERE c2.MasterID IS NOT NULL
) u
GROUP BY u.MasterID
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Why `MAX` and not `Count`?

Comment: MAX will give you the ID of the child row so that you know which row it was (e.g. to join to it, maybe). Using COUNT would return '1' in the first column of each row of the result set since each row represents a group of 1 item.

Comment: I think COUNT(1) is just an old habit. A DB guy once told me way back in the early 2000s that this was an optimization (as opposed to COUNT(somecolumn)). If it were even true then, I bet it's not true anymore. So COUNT(1) and COUNT(columnname) probably result is functionally identical query plans that perform identically.

Comment: So it probably works only if you SELECT from only one table. However I need to select from multiple ones.

Comment: I think you might need a subquery, then. One approach might be to UNION the results of queries that produce the (ID, MasterID) on each child table, and then do the GROUP BY on that UNION'd result. One second, and I'll add it to my answer above.

Comment: Oops. You would need to UNION ALL, not just UNION. Answer updated.